# How to optimize the Cursor to the Set based operator query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, optimization, cursor, set-operations

I had cursor in my stored procedure. I have updated to while loop to execute faster. But my while loops takes same  long time. Please help me to debug my script. Please find my below code.

I need the help in updating Cursor to set based operator Query in MS SQL.

```
DECLARE @orderArray INT
    ,@LeftTSMKEY NVARCHAR(250)
    ,@ListElid NVARCHAR(250)
    ,@ListType NVARCHAR(250)
    ,@ListType_Prev NVARCHAR(250)

SET @ListType_Prev = ''
SET @inc = 0

DECLARE cursql CURSOR
FOR
SELECT ListElid
    ,ListType
    ,orderArray
    ,LeftTSMKEY
FROM QAT_ListElid
ORDER BY ListType
    ,orderArray

OPEN cursql

FETCH NEXT
FROM cursql
INTO @ListElid
    ,@ListType
    ,@orderArray
    ,@LeftTSMKEY

WHILE (@@Fetch_status = 0)
BEGIN
    IF @ListType <> @ListType_Prev
    BEGIN
        SET @inc = 0
        SET @ListType_Prev = @ListType
    END
    ELSE IF @ListType = @ListType_Prev
    BEGIN
        SET @inc = @inc + 1
    END

    IF @inc <> @orderArray
    BEGIN
        INSERT [QAT_ListElid2] (
            [ListElid]
            ,[ListType]
            ,[orderArray]
            ,[LeftTSMKEY]
            )
        VALUES (
            @ListElid
            ,@ListType
            ,@inc
            ,@LeftTSMKEY + CAST(@inc AS NVARCHAR(10)) + ']'
            )
    END

    FETCH NEXT
    FROM cursql
    INTO @ListElid
        ,@ListType
        ,@orderArray
        ,@LeftTSMKEY
END

CLOSE cursql

DEALLOCATE cursql
```

Please find below sample data

[image]

```
ListElid    ListType    orderArray  LeftTSMKEY
1000:odl5:7pt_ToxAcuDo[0]   1000:odl5:7pt_ToxAcuDo  0   ToxAcuDo[
106i:odl5:7pt_ToxAcuDo[0]   106i:odl5:7pt_ToxAcuDo  0   ToxAcuDo[
107:107:7pt_NIL[0]  107:107:7pt_NIL 0   NIL[
107:1827:7pt_NIL[0] 107:1827:7pt_NIL    0   NIL[
107:1827:7pt_NIL[1] 107:1827:7pt_NIL    1   NIL[
107:1827:7pt_NIL[3] 107:1827:7pt_NIL    3   NIL[
107:1hqn:7pt_NIL[0] 107:1hqn:7pt_NIL    0   NIL[
107:1hqn:7pt_NIL[1] 107:1hqn:7pt_NIL    1   NIL[
107:1rj7:7pt_NIL[0] 107:1rj7:7pt_NIL    0   NIL[
107:1rj7:7pt_NIL[1] 107:1rj7:7pt_NIL    1   NIL[
107:1rsg:7pt_NIL[0] 107:1rsg:7pt_NIL    0   NIL[
107:1s2r:7pt_NIL[0] 107:1s2r:7pt_NIL    0   NIL[
107:1s2r:7pt_NIL[1] 107:1s2r:7pt_NIL    1   NIL[
107:1s2r:7pt_NIL[2] 107:1s2r:7pt_NIL    2   NIL[
107:1s2r:7pt_NIL[4] 107:1s2r:7pt_NIL    4   NIL[
107:1vf:7pt_ NIL[0] 107:1vf:7pt_NIL    0    NIL[
```

Comment: If possible, post sample data.

Comment: The sample data needs to be as text, not a picture.

Comment: @Zhorov okay as per your request

Comment: @tripleee Oh trying to update with set .

Comment: In addition to sample data as text, consider posting it in SQL syntax, e.g. `create table ...` and `insert ...`. That would get close to making a [MRE]. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Yunnosch trying to update with text to table

Comment: You are doing well. Good luck.

Comment: @DataBase This statement inserts only two rows in the `QAT_ListElid2` table. Is this the expected results?

Answer (score 0):

They are based on the DECLARE CURSOR syntax and are used mainly in Transact-SQL scripts, stored procedures and triggers. Transact-SQL cursors are implemented on the server and are managed by Transact-SQL statements sent from the client to the server. They may also be contained in batches, stored procedures, or triggers.

Like `INT`, `VARCHAR` and other data types, Cursors are declared in T-SQL batches. SQL Server comes with associated instructions to manage it:

1. OPEN to tell SQL Server to run the query and populate cursor with results set;
2. CLOSE to tell SQL Server to release resources used by cursor;
3. FETCH to tell SQL Server to retrieve a specific row from cursor. When we use this function, we can get the outcome of FETCH instruction in @@FETCH_STATUS variable. If it’s set to 0, this means that the instruction succeeded.

Comment: Several of your earlier posts across the Stack Exchange network have been flagged as spam. Please review the [promotion policy](/help/promotion) and refrain from posting links to your web site where they are not a substantial part of your question or answer.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question anyway. The question is not asking for some arbitrary general information about cursors. It is asking how to get rid of them in a specific case

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, the next statement is a possible solution.

Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE QAT_ListElid (
    ListElid nvarchar(250),  
    ListType nvarchar(250), 
    orderArray int, 
    LeftTSMKEY nvarchar(250)
)
INSERT INTO QAT_ListElid
    (ListElid, ListType, orderArray, LeftTSMKEY)
VALUES
    ('1000:odl5:7pt_ToxAcuDo[0]',   '1000:odl5:7pt_ToxAcuDo',   0, 'ToxAcuDo['),
    ('106i:odl5:7pt_ToxAcuDo[0]',   '106i:odl5:7pt_ToxAcuDo',   0, 'ToxAcuDo['),
    ('107:107:7pt_NIL[0]',          '107:107:7pt_NIL',          0, 'NIL['),
    ('107:1827:7pt_NIL[0]',         '107:1827:7pt_NIL',         0, 'NIL['),         -- 107:1827:7pt_NIL
    ('107:1827:7pt_NIL[1]',         '107:1827:7pt_NIL',         1, 'NIL['),         -- 107:1827:7pt_NIL
    ('107:1827:7pt_NIL[3]',         '107:1827:7pt_NIL',         3, 'NIL['),         -- 107:1827:7pt_NIL
    ('107:1hqn:7pt_NIL[0]',         '107:1hqn:7pt_NIL',         0, 'NIL['),
    ('107:1hqn:7pt_NIL[1]',         '107:1hqn:7pt_NIL',         1, 'NIL['),
    ('107:1rj7:7pt_NIL[0]',         '107:1rj7:7pt_NIL',         0, 'NIL['),
    ('107:1rj7:7pt_NIL[1]',         '107:1rj7:7pt_NIL',         1, 'NIL['),
    ('107:1rsg:7pt_NIL[0]',         '107:1rsg:7pt_NIL',         0, 'NIL['),
    ('107:1s2r:7pt_NIL[0]',         '107:1s2r:7pt_NIL',         0, 'NIL['),         -- 107:1s2r:7pt_NIL
    ('107:1s2r:7pt_NIL[1]',         '107:1s2r:7pt_NIL',         1, 'NIL['),         -- 107:1s2r:7pt_NIL
    ('107:1s2r:7pt_NIL[2]',         '107:1s2r:7pt_NIL',         2, 'NIL['),         -- 107:1s2r:7pt_NIL
    ('107:1s2r:7pt_NIL[4]',         '107:1s2r:7pt_NIL',         4, 'NIL['),         -- 107:1s2r:7pt_NIL
    ('107:1vf:7pt_ NIL[0]',         '107:1vf:7pt_NIL',          0, 'NIL[')
CREATE TABLE QAT_ListElid2 (
    ListElid nvarchar(250),  
    ListType nvarchar(250), 
    orderArray int, 
    LeftTSMKEY nvarchar(250)
)
```

Statement:

```
;WITH ChangesCTE AS (
    SELECT 
        ListElid, ListType, orderArray, LeftTSMKEY,
        CASE 
            WHEN ListType = LAG(ListType) OVER (PARTITION BY ListType ORDER BY orderArray) THEN 1 
            ELSE 0
        END AS [Change]
    FROM QAT_ListElid
), FinalCTE AS (
    SELECT 
        ListElid, ListType, orderArray, LeftTSMKEY,
        SUM([Change]) OVER (PARTITION BY ListType ORDER BY ListType, orderArray) AS [inc]
    FROM ChangesCTE
)
INSERT INTO QAT_ListElid2
    ([ListElid], [ListType], [orderArray], [LeftTSMKEY])
SELECT 
    ListElid, 
    ListType, 
    [inc] AS orderArray, 
    LeftTSMKEY + CAST([inc] as nvarchar(10)) + ']' AS LeftTSMKEY
FROM FinalCTE
WHERE orderArray <> [inc]
```

or anotehr statement as second option:

```
INSERT INTO QAT_ListElid2
    ([ListElid], [ListType], [orderArray], [LeftTSMKEY])
SELECT 
    ListElid, 
    ListType, 
    [inc] AS orderArray, 
    LeftTSMKEY + CAST([inc] as nvarchar(10)) + ']' AS LeftTSMKEY
FROM (
    SELECT 
        ListElid, ListType, orderArray, LeftTSMKEY,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ListType ORDER BY orderArray) - 1 AS [Inc]
    FROM QAT_ListElid
) t
WHERE orderArray <> [inc]
```

Result (two inserted rows):

```
--------------------------------------------------------------
ListElid            ListType            orderArray  LeftTSMKEY
--------------------------------------------------------------
107:1827:7pt_NIL[3] 107:1827:7pt_NIL    2           NIL[2]
107:1s2r:7pt_NIL[4] 107:1s2r:7pt_NIL    3           NIL[3]
```